# Counting via if

Tags: python

I don't know why the number of breaches is not counted - if I do it this way:

```
def test(runs):
    runs = runs
    for i in range(0,runs):
        #some initialized parameter
        #initialize v[:,0]=v_0 
        for i in range(range(0, int(timeSteps)-1, 1)):
            #calculate v here using Runge Kutta method 
        v = v_0 + v
        
        #check if a certain threshold has been reached
        if max(v[:]-v_0) > 50:
            print("breach")
test(10)
```

then I get 5 times the word breach as output

but if I do it like this

```
def test(runs):
    runs=runs
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,runs):
        #some initialized parameter
        #initialize v[:,0]=v_0 
        for i in range(range(0, int(timeSteps)-1, 1)):
            #calculate v here using Runge Kutta method 
        v = v_0 + v
        
        #check if a certain threshold has been reached
        if max(v[:]-v_0) > 50:
            count += 1
    
    return count
test(10)
```

then i get the initialized value count=0 and not count=5 as return value. why does this not work?

Comment: What are you looking at to get the returned `count` value? Your example code throws away the return value of the `test()` function.

Comment: i want to call the function test, and want to count how many times max(v[:]-v_0) > 50 and want to get this integer number back as a return value

Comment: please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the returned value in any variable,

Change:

```
test(10)
```

To:

```
returnedValue = test(10)
print(returnedValue)
```

You can also do this:

```
print(test(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

in the second loop, you use the variable `i` when it is already declared in the loop just above. Try to modify it using another variable like `j`:

```
def test(runs):
    runs = runs
    for i in range(0,runs):
        #some initialized parameter
        #initialize v[:,0]=v_0 
        for j in range(range(0, int(timeSteps)-1, 1)):
            #calculate v here using Runge Kutta method 
        v = v_0 + v
        
        #check if a certain threshold has been reached
        if max(v[:]-v_0) > 50:
            print("breach")
test(10)
```